# Convert array to list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

```
function array_to_list(arr) {
  list = null

  for (i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = { value: arr[i], rest: list };
  }

  return list;
}
x = array_to_list([10, 20]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

the output I get is :

```
{"value":10,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":{"rest":null}}}
```

but I want

```
{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

how can I solve that problem? That is to change the last rest to null instead of another object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code, set `i = arr.length - 1` as the initial value of `i`. Since arrays have 0 based index, the last item's index is one less than the arrays length:

```js
function array_to_list(arr) {
  let rest = null

  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rest = { value: arr[i], rest };
  }

  return rest;
}

const result = array_to_list([10, 20]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I would use [`Array.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) to iterate the list from the end, and set the initial value to `null`:

```js
const array_to_list = arr =>
  arr.reduceRight((rest, value) => ({
    value,
    rest
  }), null)

const result = array_to_list([10, 20]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: how can I put arr.reduceright it in my function?

Comment: You don't need to put it in your own function. Just use the function in the ansewr. I've added a fix for you code.

Comment: Which one is more efficient? in O(n) complexity

Comment: Both have the same Big O complexity - O(n). If you don't have more than 10,000 elements in the array, you probably won't feel a difference. If you do, the for loop is slightly faster. The `reduceRight` is more readable.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes are 0 based, so given the array `[10, 20]` the index of `10` is `0` and the index of `20` is `1`, but your loop starts from `arr.length`, which is 2, so the first `arr[i]` evaluates to `undefined` and the loop runs one time more than it should. When iterating through an array backwards, you should generally start from `length - 1`.

```js
function array_to_list(arr) {
  list = null

  for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = { value: arr[i], rest: list };
  }

  return list;
}
x = array_to_list([10, 20]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```